# Conditionals and Matrices Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a matrix {{a,b},{c,d}} in Mathematica, in which elements a,b,c,d can vary depending on some variable parameter. Is there a way in which I can have an if statement in which can terminate if the element *a* is between some value(conditional statement)?

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
a = 0;
test[] := While[True,
  If[matrix[[1, 1]] > 4 && matrix[[1, 1]] < 6,
   Return[matrix],
   ++a]]
test[]
```

> {{5, b}, {c, d}}